# Inserting into database via web service

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, web-services

I'm working on inserting users into my database via a web service, but each time I try to do so, the web service returns the following error:
TinyTds::Error: There are more column in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause.
I don't see the problem as there are 5 values in each statement.

```
post '/insert_users/' do
conn = TinyTds::Client.new(...)
username = params[:username]
password = params[:password]
phone_number = params[:phone_number]
profile_state = params[:profile_state]
clasa = params[:clasa]
sql = "insert into ServerUsers(Username, Passwords,Phone_Number, Profile_State, Class) values('username, password, phone_number, profile_state, clasa')"
cursor = conn.execute(sql)
end
```

This is how I try to insert into the database via the web service:

http://address:port/insert_users/?username=user3&password=parola3&phone_number=0723567432&profile_state=A&clasa=2

I am using Advanced REST client to test the webservice.

I used the tutorial here: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must only quote strings:

**Change it from:**

```
sql = "insert into ServerUsers(Username, Passwords,Phone_Number, Profile_State, Class) values('username, password, phone_number, profile_state, clasa')"
```

**to**

```
sql = "insert into ServerUsers(Username, Passwords,Phone_Number, Profile_State, Class) values('#{username}', '#{password}', '#{phone_number}', #{profile_state}, '#{clasa')"
```

i not know how to quote each string

Comment: In my database, Phone_Number is type int and if i put quotes I get a new error: failed when converting varchar value 'phone_number' to data type int

Comment: @meow - i have searched by google and found that you so reference to a variable #{data} . i have change my answer, but its not tested

Comment: Thank you very much :D it works. You are a life saver :)